# Visual Studio shows error CS0029 for types in non-global alias

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a wrapper around two different versions of a communication library that work with different versions of my company's database. These communication libraries have classes with identical fully-qualified names, so I am loading the references into different aliases; I've tried it with one or the other in the global alias and with both in non-global aliases, and in both cases Visual Studio 2012 complains that I have compile errors. In specific, in both of my wrapper classes, I am fetching a connection from a factory method

```
extern alias MyAliasVersionX;
using MyAliasVersionX::Example.MyNamespace;
...
private Connection _connection;
...
_connection = Connection.Create(environmentName); // this returns an Example.MyNamespace.Connection--but this is where the compile error happens
```

The code is virtually identical in both classes; the biggest difference is the version on the alias in the using statement at the top. In one class (it appears to be whichever reference is listed first), everything works fine, no error. In the other class, Visual Studio tells me that the line noted above will produce a compile error because Connection.Create() returns the *other* version of Connection object (i.e., MyAliasVersionY::Example.MyNamespace.Connection instead of MyAliasVersionX::Example.MyNamespace.Connection).

**Here's the important part:** when I actually Build the project, it compiles fine and runs fine, and the error showing in the Error List pane disappears... until I make any change to the code, at which point it comes back, still never causing a Build error.

Is this a bug in Visual Studio? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Fishy - Try closing VS, reboot the computer. Open it back up and see if it goes away.

Comment: No dice. Persists after reboot, and is reproducible on a colleague's machine (though he gets it in the _other_ version's wrapper class--what!?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Visual Studio dating back to VS-2008, according to Microsoft. It won't likely be fixed until a major overhaul of VB.NET/C# editing (called "Roslyn") is released. (If you're dissatisfied with that, upvote my Connect feedback below to let Microsoft know!)

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786107/visual-studio-shows-error-cs0029-for-types-in-non-global-alias